# Is there a way to view docs for all gems in a project?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently working my way through the [Rust language introduction docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), and I was pretty impressed by the package manager [Cargo](http://doc.crates.io/index.html).

Calling `cargo doc --open` in a project directory opens a browser window which shows the documentation for the project, as well as the docs for each crate (package) used in the project.

Is there a similar command - maybe in Bundler, Rake or some other gem - that generates and displays documentation for all gems used in a Ruby application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is part of RubyGems - specifically, the `gem` command (the same one used to install gems).

To view info for the gems installed to your *system* e.g. the ones you installed via `gem install` and not through a Gemfile, you use `gem server` and then visit the web interface at http://localhost:8808

To see documentation for only gemfile-specific packages, you can use `bundle exec gem server`.

Comment: Looks like `bundle exec gem server` is what I'm after. Thanks!